# light gravitational wave interaction

Tags: gravitational-waves

What happens when light photos and gravitation waves collide?  Like can the photon "surf" on the gravitational wave and change direction, wavelength, velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Light follows geodesics and gravity waves modifies spaces thus geodesics, so the light should be slightly deflected (but it will be the opposite way at opposed phase. This might still cause an offset, as for refraction through a  a glass sheet). Note that both travel at the same speed, so interaction can only occurs for different directions of propagation.